# How to match paragraphs using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like a regex that matches paragraphs, so for example :

> The red brown fox, did something.
> [newline] I don't remember this text.
>
> [newline]
>
> [newline]
> So, instead I'll say blah blah.
> [newline] Blah.

would return an array like this:

```
['The red brown...', 'So instead I'll say...']
```

I already have this regex (that I stole, shh): `/(?:[^\r\n]|\r(?!\n))+/gm`

However this pattern matches both linebreaks (one newline) and paragraphs breaks (two newline). How can I match the body of text between paragraphs, but not split the matches between single linebreaks?

Comment: I need to match the body of text, not the actual newlines, I'm sorry. Let me edit that.

Comment: Ok, what is the linebreak style you are interested in?

Comment: "I already have this regex (that I stole, shh)" bad Sebastian :D

Comment: I have come up with `.match(/(?:.|(?:\r?\n|\r)(?!\r?\n|\r))+/g)` but I do not like it. This is good: `s.match(/.+(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)(?!\r?\n|\r).*)*/g)`. Splitting is better: `var s = "The red brown fox, did something.\r\nI don't remember this text.\r\n\r\nSo, instead I'll say blah blah.\r\nBlah.";
    console.log(s.split(/(?:\r\n){2,}/g));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, splitting did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split with the linebreak (sequence, depends on the linebreak style) with a `{2,}` [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```js
var s = "The red brown fox, did something.\r\nI don't remember this text.\r\n\r\nSo, instead I'll say blah blah.\r\nBlah.";    
console.log(s.split(/(?:\r\n){2,}/));
```

So, here, `/(?:\r\n){2,}/` matches 2 or more consecutive CR+LF sequences. If the linebreak style is LF only, use a simpler `/\n{2,}/` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex `/(.+)((\r?\n.+)*)/gm` to capture only what can be considered a paragraph. According to your description, a paragraph can have normal text and single line breaks. The following example implements this solution.

```js
// Orignial input
var input = `

    The red brown fox, did something.
I don't remember this text

So, instead I'll say blah blah. 
Blah.

another paragraph
`;

document.write('<code>ORIGNIAL</code><pre>' + input + '</pre><hr>');

var 
  regex = /(.+)((\r?\n.+)*)/gm,
  matches, output = []; // output is used to store all paragraphs

while (matches = regex.exec(input)) {
  output.push(matches[0]);
  document.write('<code>PARAGRAPH ' + output.length + '</code><pre>' + matches[0] + '</pre><hr>');
}
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: lightGray;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
hr {
  border: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: This still matches single linebreaks, not just paragraphs.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen you expect line breaks to be inside the paragraph?

Comment: Yes, I want linebreaks inside paragraphs.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen late response but I've updated my answer.